# Is there a compiler-safe way to access a member field of an Object when its class is not known at compile-time?

Tags: java

I am currently creating a class, which has a field of *Object* type.

My issue is that when accessing a member of this object, the compiler throws a *Symbol not found* error, as the class is not known at compile-time. Is there a way to ignore this, or mark it as resolve later, i.e. at runtime?

Specifically:
I have a linked list that collects a list of classes, which store information about UI controls, as well as storing a reference to the real UI control (this being the Object field as obj). The Object (obj) has a hitbox member (hb), which I am trying to set a property of.

The offending line is:

`items.get(this.curIndex).obj.hb.hovered=true;`

As I am not at liberty to publish the source, here's a mockup for easier understanding of what's happening.

```
public class MenuButton {
    public HitBox hb;
    ...
}

public class NameEdit {
    public HitBox hb;
    ...
}

public class VolumeSlider {
    public HitBox hb;
    ...
}

public class HitBox {
    public Boolean hovered;
    ...
}

public class AObject {
    public String label;
    public String hint;
    public Object obj;
    ...
}

public class AContainer {
    public LinkedList<AObject> items=new LinkedList<>();

    public void add(Object obj) {
        items.add(obj);
    }
    ...
}

//elsewhere:
    public LinkedList<AContainer> containers=new LinkedList<>();
    ...
    containers.get(0).items.get(0).obj.hb.hovered=true;
```

What this comes down to is that *AObject* has an *obj* member, which the compiler cannot infer the class of, thus I get a cannot find symbol, since Java cannot check at compile-time that when *obj* is set, it's going to have a *hb* field.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it an option to use generics?

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I understand, I would need to modify all the classes that *obj* can point to. Let me know if I am wrong though, generics weren't the first thing I thought of, having a Golang background ☺️

Comment: @Erion You don’t need to modify the contained classes to use generics. You only need to modify your linked list class. Better yet, use Java’s built-in list class which already does this (and don’t use a linked list, it’s probably not what you want, linked lists are almost always worse that array-backed lists).

Comment: @Erion Please [edit] your question to include the source codes you have to show, where the problem is, where you have lists, how the UI is involved, where you use the `obj` field and how you want to access the hitbox member `hb`.

Comment: @konrad-rudolph Thanks for the tip. I am still not entirely sure how generics could help me, unfortunately, as I am chaining an assignment to an unknown, and to the compiler unexistent, member field.
@Progman: I am unfortunately unable to share the exact source code, hence my very generic line. Essentially what it comes down to is that a variable (Object obj), has a hb (HitBox hb) field, which has a property (hb.hovered), which I'd like to modify.
`obj.hb.hovered=true;`

Comment: @Erion The first attempt would be to change `Object obj` to `T obj`, where `T` is a generic type. But without the source code it's hard to tell how to solve it.

Comment: I see. This way I could still store any class in *obj*. The question is, would the compiler accept obj.hb.hovered=true, i.e. would it still throw an error if it can't infer that T, as a generic type, does not have *hb* as a member, which has a *hovered* property?

Comment: @Erion It will work when the generic type in that specific case will resolve to a type, which has a `hb` field, which uses a type which has a `hovered` field. The type `Object` does not have these properties.

Comment: Do I have to do anything specific, e.g. declare T as a specific type, such as *T<UIControl>*, when I'd like to access the *hb* field? If yes, this could be problematic, as I could have about a hundred different classes that an Object field could hold, all guaranteed to have a *hb* field with a type.

Comment: @Erion Does the `hb` field belong to a base class you can use? Can you use an interface which have a method like `getHitBox()` which would be implemented by the classes? It's very difficult to say or maybe too broad for how to solve the problem you have. Please [edit] your question to include source code which shows the problem you have, the different classes you use and how you want to connect them and access the data you have.

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to share the source, but I've edited my post to include a mockup. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Erion Btw.: You should use getters to access fields, not directly access them (and don't have them public), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they are part of the original implementation, as of course it's not a good practice to access fields directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the class `AObject` to use a generic type for the type for `obj`. It might look like this:

```
public class AObject<T> {
    public String label;
    public String hint;
    public T obj;
    // [...]]
}
```

Then you add a new interface for objects which have a hitbox.

```
public interface HasHitBox {
    public HitBox getHitBox();
}
```

Your classes `MenuButton`, `NameEdit` and `VolumeSlider` will implement this interface. Then you can change the field

```
public LinkedList<AObject> items=new LinkedList<>();
```

to

```
public LinkedList<AObject<HasHitBox>> items=new LinkedList<>();
```

Now you can add `AObject` objects which reference an object, which implements the `HasHitBox` interface. And that gives you the ability to call `getHitBox()`.